# Is there some way to avoid valgrind's "Unrecognised instruction" error?

Tags: valgrind

I tried to run my program with valgrind 3.9.0 (and my OS is redhat 7.2 in case that's relevant).

I got this error message:

```
vex amd64->IR: unhandled instruction bytes: 0x66 0xF 0x1B 0x4 0x24 0x66 0xF 0x1B
vex amd64->IR:   REX=0 REX.W=0 REX.R=0 REX.X=0 REX.B=0
vex amd64->IR:   VEX=0 VEX.L=0 VEX.nVVVV=0x0 ESC=0F 
vex amd64->IR:   PFX.66=1 PFX.F2=0 PFX.F3=0 
==37534== valgrind: Unrecognised instruction at address 0x4015237.
```

I found this page which looks somewhat relevant: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1087933.
It seems to imply that this is a known problem (or at least it was one back in 2014)

Is there some workaround for this problem or some way for me to avoid this valgrind error?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to a newer version of valgrind, which will contain the fix.
Current version is 3.11, but 3.12 will very soon (a few days max) be out.